What is reduced in the reaction of magnesium with oxygen?
What is reduced in the reaction $$
2\mathrm{Mg} + \mathrm{O}_2 \rightarrow 2\mathrm{MgO} $$
An oxygen molecule or an oxygen atom ?

In the reaction of magnesium with oxygen $\ce{O2}$, the oxygen atom is reduced from $0$ to $-2$. This cannot be said of the molecule $\ce{O2}$. The oxidation number is a number attached to an atom, not to a molecule. But the molecule $\ce{O2}$ can be called an oxidant. The situation is more clear in the case of $\ce{KMnO4}$
$\ce{O2}$ is like $\ce{KMnO4}$. Surprisingly, $\ce{KMnO4}$  can be called an oxidant. This is due to the $\ce{Mn}$ atom that is the only oxidizing agent of $\ce{KMnO4}$. The $\ce{K}$ and $\ce{O}$ atoms in $\ce{KMnO4}$ are not oxidant. They do not change their oxidation number. Only $\ce{Mn}$ changes its oxidation number in a reaction of $\ce{KMnO4}$. $\ce{Mn}$ is at $+7$ in $\ce{KMnO4}$ : it goes down to a smaller value in a redox reaction : $\ce{Mn(VII)}$ is a strong oxidant. And $\ce{KMnO4}$ can also be called an oxidant, even if $\ce{KMnO4}$ has no oxidation number.

O2 is reduced in steps Forming superoxides, peroxides each with their oxidation numbers. Oxidation numbers are a tool to balance equations not a means of explaining mechanisms.
